# Unable to get intent filters from a package

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-package-managers

I want to list all the intent filters that are present in an package.

I am trying to do it using PackageManager class.
I have set the flag PackageManager.GET_INTENT_FILTERS while fetching the PackageInfo object.
But I dont know how to use it.

I was able to get all the info related to activites and receivers using the respective flags, but dunno how to proceed for intent-filters.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: @TusharPandey - none that I know of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like intent filters are not exposed in the API and the flag effectively does nothing: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3217